# Boolean expression: how to find "don't care" numbers?

Tags: boolean-algebra

The boolean expression `z+w'` is received after simplification of the expression

```
vw'y+v'wz+vyz+v'w'x'y'+v'w'xyz+vw'y'z'+vw'xy'z+v'w'yz'
```

We don't know what are the don't care numbers, what are the numbers that are for sure don't care expressions?

I tried solving this a few ways, but none of them worked.
I find it more important for me to understand the way to solve this question, so please provide a detailed answer.

I tried to use a truth table with 5 variables, and then a Karnaugh map, but I'm still struggling.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you saying that the large expression reduces to the smaller expression if certain input combinations are designated as "don't cares"? And you want to know what these combinations are?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Set up a Karnaugh map with $vwx$ on top and $yz$ on the side, like this:

$$\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\text{vwx}\backslash \text{yz}&000&001&011&010&110&111&101&100\\\hline
00\\\hline
01\\\hline
11\\\hline
10
\end{array}$$
Now fill in the map with 1's in the places given by the larger expression. In order for the larger expression to reduce to `z+w'`, there must be 1's or "don't care"s in row 2 and 3 as well as in columns 1,2,7,8.

You will find that 6 "don't care"s are needed.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the answer but that's what I have tried.
for example: if I take a look at the larger expression and I choose the first number combination it gives me $vw'y = 101 = 5$ then i mark it in the table at the place of number 5 as 1 right?

then I fill the rest of the numbers same technique as mentioned above...

if that's the way, then what's next?

Comment: First, don't think of the bit combinations as numbers, just as bit combinations. Second, the columns give combinations of $vwx$, not $vwy$. So in which columns is $vw=10$? And in which rows is $y=1$? Put a 1 in the intersection of those columns and rows. Continue in the same way with the rest of the expression.

Comment: Ok got you,
i made my K-map as $vw$ rows and $xyz$ columns but lets do your way!.
but the example you give me there are 2 options to put 1 for $vw=10$ and $y=1$ how can i know which one of them?

Comment: Put 1 in all of them.

Comment: Many thanks! sometimes all you need is to put it in the tables and the answer is in front of your eyes.